# How to set environment variable in Google App Engine based java backend server which is a secret stored in GitHub repo via GitHub Actions workflow?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, github-actions

I have been at it since 2 days and I did check this SO [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65330588/how-can-i-pass-a-variable-from-github-actions-workflow-to-a-gae-app-yaml-file) that looks similar but it does not seem to work at all.

My Setup

- A spring boot API backend on App Engine setup using Gradle.
- I use some external api whose api key I store as a secret in GitHub Repo secrets. I deploy the app on Google App Engine using the **google-github-actions/deploy-appengine@v0.2.0** action.
  In my `app.yaml` file which is in the root I have a simple setup -

```yaml
runtime: java17
instance_class: F2
env_variables:
  EXT_API_KEY: $EXT-API-KEY
  DUMMY_ENV_VAR: $DUMMY_ENV_VAR
```

I have the dummy env var just as a check since it contains a useless string. I have a dummy endpoint that returns the dummy env var so that I can see if the backend is actually able to get the correct value of the environment variable.
I use `System.getenv("DUMMY_ENV_VAR")` to get the environment variable.
In my deployment yaml file for GitHub action I have -

```yaml
name: Deploy Project to App Engine

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

  workflow_dispatch:

# env: 
#   EXT_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.EXT_API_KEY }}
#   DUMMY_ENV_VAR: ${{ secrets.GCP_DUMMY_ENV_VAR }}

  
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploying to Google Cloud
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Deploy to App Engine
        id: deploy
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-appengine@v0.2.0
        env: 
          EXT_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.EXT_API_KEY }}
          DUMMY_ENV_VAR: ${{ secrets.GCP_DUMMY_ENV_VAR }}
        with:
        #   env_vars: |-
        #     EXT_API_KEY=${{ env.EXT_API_KEY }}
        #     DUMMY_ENV_VAR=${{ env.GCP_DUMMY_ENV_VAR }}
          deliverables: app.yaml
          version: v1
          credentials: ${{ secrets.GCP_SERVICE_CREDENTIALS }}

      - name: Test
        run: curl "${{ steps.deploy.outputs.url }}"
```

I have tried many variations of setting up environment variable in the deployment yaml file, as well many ways I found online like with single quote, double quotes, with parenthesis and without parenthesis (in app.yaml). I also tried it like as stated in the [action doc](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-appengine#inputs) -

```
with:
  env_vars: |-
    EXT_API_KEY=${{ env.EXT_API_KEY }}
    DUMMY_ENV_VAR=${{ env.GCP_DUMMY_ENV_VAR }}
```

but nothing seems to work. Either the output you see below is null or just the unparsed value.

Example output when I call the dummy endpoint -

```json
{
    "DUMMY_VAR": [
        "$DUMMY_ENV_VAR"
    ],
    ...
    // here I get that the offcial api key is incorrect which is easy to guess since the dummy env variable is also not correctly parsed.
```

which means that GitHub action is not actually passing the key value to App Engine or that app.yaml cannot setup the environment variable.

Any hints on how to set this up correctly?

Comment: Would it be an option to use a `sed` command line directly in a workflow job step to edit the `app.yaml` file replacing a specific text by the Github Secret you want?

Comment: Ideally no, but at this point I want to get it working somehow...so i am willing to try that as well @GuiFalourd

Comment: If you want to try it, the command would look like this: `sed -i.back "s| DUMMY_ENV_VAR|${DUMMY_ENV_VAR}|g" ./path/to/app.yaml`. Just be careful to not use the same syntax for the KEY and the VALUE in the `app.yaml` file (otherwise the `sed` command line will replace both fields). Therefore, don't use `DUMMY_ENV_VAR: DUMMY_ENV_VAR` but prefer `ENV_VAR: DUMMY_ENV_VAR` (to replace just DUMMY_ENV_VAR).

Answer (score 0):

If you have secret, you must keep them secret. In your current process, you want to set in plain text your secret, that's an anti-pattern!

The solution here is to use [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager). Update the secret at each deployment, or only when the secret change (manual update).

Then, in your code, instead of reading an environment variable, you have to access to the latest secret version to get value (you can also access to a specific version).

By doing that, you keep your secrets secret end to end and you are more secure!